# Целостность данных

Tags: mysql, sql

Начал создавать следующую таблицу:

```
id | uid | sid | type | mask
```

**sid** - id из таблицы

**type** - тип sid, т.е. определяет таблицу откуда sid будет браться (на данный момент 2 таблицы - это **Подразделения** и **Пользователи**)

Как мне обеспечить целостность данных связи sid-а с различными таблицами, в зависимости от type? подскажите литературу.

**UPD:**

Немного распишу смысл таблиц (*упростил для понимания*). Пользователю дается разрешение (или запрещается) на отправку тому или иному пользователю сообщения, а так же той или иной группе пользователей (подразделению). Кроме пользователей и подразделений могут появится id проектов (т.е. разрешить всем кто связан с каким либо проектом), id контрактов и т.д. Но данная доработка по логике не должна затрагивать сами таблицы подразделений, пользователей и т.д., поэтому выносится в отдельную таблицу.

В реализации связки **sid + type** и **column1 + column2 + ...** обсуждали с напарником и пришли к выводу использовать первый вариант (собственно во втором случае целостность понятно как организовать)

Связь таблиц N-N, связываются uid-ы с различными id других таблиц (в том числе и id пользователей). Суть задачи: хранить настройки "доступа" для пользователя

*Заранее спасибо*

Comment: по-моему так не делают. Вместо sid нужно сделать два nullable-столбца sid_for_type1, sid_for_type2. В первый класть id из 1й таблицы, во второй - из второй.

Comment: @atwice в развитии проекта будут появляться новые таблицы, с новыми ссылками. При этом, в данной таблице будет увеличиваться кол-во столбцов.

Comment: Тогда делают так:
1) в первой таблице (назовём её root) не заводят sid вообще никакой. И type не заводят.
2) В каждую новую таблицу типа "Подразделения", "Пользователи" добавляют столбец root_id, указывающий на первую таблицу.

Кстати, тут важно, какое отношение между таблицами. 1:1, 1:много?

Comment: @IVsevolod, вполне логично, что база будет расти, как собственно и ее структура. В одном @atwice прав на 100% - так делать не стоит. Какой тип связи у вас будет (1-n или n-n)? Не пробовали сделать обратную связь, **Подразделения** и **Пользователи** к вашей таблице?

    department_id|your_table_id|data
    user_id|your_table_id|data

Более развернутая схема со связями поможет нам помочь вам.

Comment: Все же сложность в понимании ваших мыслей некоторая есть. Вы правы, вы выносите в отдельную таблицу связи, но Вам все же стоит задуматься, чтобы использовать разные таблицы для связи между пользователями и (пользователями, группами, документами...)

Comment: @Dex спасибо, подумаю :)

а так, немного еще поясню, почему все-же пришли к такому. Есть Руководитель, который может получать уведомления от действий того или иного пользователя. При этом руководитель может настроить у себя учетку так, чтобы не получать письма от конкретного пользователя / от пользователей конкретного подразделения / от пользователей сидящих на одном проекте и т.д. Вот и решили в одну таблицу это все дело записать, чтобы работать только с ней...

Comment: @IVsevolod, у вас количество записей в одной таблице будет расти (худший случай) n*n (для пользователей). Возможно это не так страшно. 

Но боюсь ваша реализация не пройдет проверку по нормальным формам. У вас есть транзитивные зависимости, что противоречит 3НФ и не только. Ключем в данной таблице должен являться `ID`, но `mask` еще зависит от `type`, что противоречит 2НФ, при которой все неключевые атрибуты должны зависеть только от потенциального ключа, а это в свою очередь противоречит вашим условиям. Естетсвенно сперва проверка на 2НФ, потом 3ю, может 3я самоликвидируется:)

Comment: @IVsevolod, а если будет поставлена задача - запретить получение писем от определенного пользователя на определенном проекте (или в определенном подразделении)?

Ваша структура с этим заданием справится только если будет выделена определенная табличка, в которой будет указан тот самый проект + тот самый пользователь. В своей табличке вы будете ссылать на id из новой таблицы.

Но с другой стороны - если эта определенная табличка будет существовать, то отпадает потребность в вашей табличке.

Так может сразу сделать предложенный вами второй вариант?

Comment: pivot не поможет?

Comment: @eicto что за pivot?, поподробнее можно? )